# Django REST framework error - name is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django 2.2 that has two apps - status and updates:

django_api
|
status
|
api
|
updates

In **django_api/urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from updates.views import (
    json_example_view, 
    JsonCBV, 
    JsonCBV2, 
    SerializedListView, 
    SerializedDetailView
)

from status.api.views import 
StatusListSearchAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/status/', status.api.urls),
    path('api/updates/', updates.api.urls),
```

In **django_api/status/api/views.py**:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.views import APIView 
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import StatusSerializer 
from status.models import Status

class StatusListSearchAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format = None):
        qs = Status.objects.all()
        serializer = StatusSeralizer(qs, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        qs = Status.objects.all()
        serializer = StatusSeralizer(qs, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class StatusAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset = Status.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatusSeralizer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Status.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
            if query is not None: 
                qs = qs.filter(content_icontains = query)
            return qs
```

In **django_api/status/api/serializers.py**:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django import forms
from status.models import Status

class StatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta: 
         model = Status
         fields = [
            'user',
            'content',
            'image']

     def validate_content(self, value):
         if len(value) > 10000:
             raise serializers.ValidationError("This is way too long.")
             return value

     def validate(self, data):
         content = data.get("content", None) 
         if content == "":
             content = None
         image = data.get("image", None)
         if content is None and image is None:
             raise serializers.ValidationError("content or image is required.")
        return data
```

When I run python manage.py runserver, I am getting an error:

```
File "...\status\api\views.py", line 26, in StatusAPIView
serializer_class = StatusSeralizer
NameError: name 'StatusSeralizer' is not defined
```

**Updated**: as indicated, this was a spelling error. However, after I imported status and from status.api imported urls, I am getting this error:

```
...\urls.py", line 39, in <module>
path('api/status/', status.api.urls),
...File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of 
include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of 
include().
```

This is my **status/api/urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import StatusAPIView, StatusCreateAPIView


 urlpatterns = [
    path('/', StatusAPIView.as_view()),
    path('create/', StatusCreateAPIView.as_view()),
    ]
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Did you try adding `import status` into your urls.py?

Comment: @kamilyrb getting a new error: "...\urls.py", line 38, in <module>
    path('api/status/', status.api.urls),
AttributeError: module 'status.api' has no attribute 'urls'"

Comment: Have you a `urls.py` file in your status module?

Comment: it is under status/api/urls.py. When I imported it, I got new error: TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: @kamilyrb updated the question with the urls.py

Comment: Okey, i found the problem. If you want to add urls of another apps, you must use include function like that :`path('api/status',include('status.api.urls'))` please try ir

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo:

You are calling: StatusSeralizer but it is: StatusSerializer

Comment: That fixed it, but I've got a new error: NameError: name 'status' is not defined. See the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see StatusCreateAPIView in you views file. Have you created this view?
Try just commenting or removing `path('create/', StatusCreateAPIView.as_view()),` and see If you still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it bro:

from rest_framework import status.

Tell me if you have sucess!